# Interactive Stock Chart, step by step animation with keyboard arrows, with Matplolib

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, data-visualization, visualization

I am trying to plot an interactive stock chart using matplotlib. It should work like this:

1. Initially it shows 60 bars in the plot (from first to the 60th bar of the the dataframe)
2. After pressing the right arrow in the keyboard, it shows the 61th bar and the first bar disappears (so, now the plot shows from the second to the 61 th of the dataframe). If I press the right arrow again the plot shows the third to the 62th, and so on. The idea here is to show a fixed amount of bars in the plot as I advance in the days by pressing the right arrow.
3. Pressing the left arrow goes one step back (eg. if the chart is on the second to the 61th, after pressing the left arrow it goes back to the first to the 60 th)

I wrote the code below, but unfortunately as I press the right arrow it only adds one more bar to the plot, the first bar never disappears. Also, when I press the left arrow nothing happens. Can somebody help? The code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv('all_stocks_5yr.csv')
df_apple = df[df['Name'] == 'AAPL'].copy()
df_apple['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_apple['date'])
df_apple.reset_index(inplace=True)

bars_to_display = 60
step = 0

#Chart Commands

x = np.arange(0,len(df_apple))
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize=(12,8), gridspec_kw={'height_ratios': [4, 1]}, sharex = True)
val_array = []
for idx, val in df_apple.iterrows():
    val_array.append(val)

# ticks top plot
ax2.set_xticks(x[::3])
#ax2.set_xticklabels(df_apple.date.dt.date[::3])
ax.set_xticks(x, minor=True)
# labels
ax.set_ylabel('USD')
ax2.set_ylabel('Volume')
# grid
ax.xaxis.grid(color='black', linestyle='dashed', which='both', alpha=0.1)
ax2.set_axisbelow(True)
ax2.yaxis.grid(color='black', linestyle='dashed', which='both', alpha=0.1)
# remove spines
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
# get max volume + 10%
mx = df_apple['volume'].max()*1.1
# define tick locations - 0 to max in 4 steps
yticks_ax2 = np.arange(0, mx+1, mx/4)
# create labels for ticks. Replace 1.000.000 by 'mi'
yticks_labels_ax2 = ['{:.2f} mi'.format(i/1000000) for i in yticks_ax2]
ax2.yaxis.tick_right() # Move ticks to the left side
# plot y ticks / skip first and last values (0 and max)
plt.yticks(yticks_ax2[1:-1], yticks_labels_ax2[1:-1])
plt.ylim(0,mx)
# title
ax.set_title('Apple Stock Price\n', loc='left', fontsize=20)

#Plot the chart, displaying the bars from 0 to bars_to_display

for i in range(0,bars_to_display):
    color = '#2CA453'
    if val_array[i]['open'] > val_array[i]['close']: color= '#F04730'
    ax.plot([x[i], x[i]], [val_array[i]['low'], val_array[i]['high']], color=color)
    ax.plot([x[i], x[i]-0.1], [val_array[i]['open'], val_array[i]['open']], color=color)
    ax.plot([x[i], x[i]+0.1], [val_array[i]['close'], val_array[i]['close']], color=color)
    ax2.bar(x[i], val_array[i]['volume'] , color='lightgrey')


plt.ion()

def on_keyboard(event):
    global step
    if event.key == 'right':
        step += 1
    elif event.key == 'left':
        step -= 1
        if step <= 0: step=0

    #Plot the chart, displaying the bars from 1: bars_to_display +1; then 2: bars_to_display +2, etc...
        
    for i in range(step,bars_to_display+step):

        color = '#2CA453'
        if val_array[i]['open'] > val_array[i]['close']: color= '#F04730'
        ax.plot([x[i], x[i]], [val_array[i]['low'], val_array[i]['high']], color=color)
        ax.plot([x[i], x[i]-0.1], [val_array[i]['open'], val_array[i]['open']], color=color)
        ax.plot([x[i], x[i]+0.1], [val_array[i]['close'], val_array[i]['close']], color=color)
        ax2.bar(x[i], val_array[i]['volume'] , color='lightgrey')
    

plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_keyboard)

plt.show()
```

obs: the dataframe that I used has the following format:

```
      index       date      open      high       low     close     volume  Name
0      1259 2013-02-08   67.7142   68.4014   66.8928   67.8542  158168416  AAPL
1      1260 2013-02-11   68.0714   69.2771   67.6071   68.5614  129029425  AAPL
2      1261 2013-02-12   68.5014   68.9114   66.8205   66.8428  151829363  AAPL
3      1262 2013-02-13   66.7442   67.6628   66.1742   66.7156  118721995  AAPL
4      1263 2013-02-14   66.3599   67.3771   66.2885   66.6556   88809154  AAPL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice work.
You need to add only two things in order to make your code working:

- `plt.draw()` at the end of `on_keyboard` function: this is necessary to update the plot
- `ax.cla()` and `ax2.cla()` before for loop in `on_keyboard` function: this is necessary to clear axis from previous plots

*However* `ax.cla()` erase grid, so I suggest you to apply some edits to your code:

- move all plotting calls (plotting for loop and layout management) inside `on_keyboard` function, so not only the plot but also the layout management will be updated one a user press  or . This allows you to avoid repeting for loop (and layout management) outside and inside of `on_keyboard`
- remove outside `on_keybaord` for loop for plotting, useless repetition
- add `ax.set_xlim` and `ax2.set_xlim` in the layout management to fix x axis limits
- add a call to `on_keyboard` just before `plt.show()` in order to draw the plot
- the previous call requires to pass to `on_keyboard` an `event` parameter: you can just pass `0` and catch it inside `on_keyboard` in a if statement

That been said, working code:
(I removed `plt.ion()` and works for me, you may need to restore it)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('all_stocks_5yr.csv')
df_apple = df[df['Name'] == 'AAPL'].copy()
df_apple['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_apple['date'])
df_apple.reset_index(inplace = True)

bars_to_display = 60
step = 0

# Chart Commands

x = np.arange(0, len(df_apple))
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize = (12, 8), gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios': [4, 1]}, sharex = True)
val_array = []
for idx, val in df_apple.iterrows():
    val_array.append(val)


def on_keyboard(event):

    global step
    if event != 0:
        if event.key == 'right':
            step += 1
        elif event.key == 'left':
            step -= 1
            if step <= 0: step = 0

    # Plot the chart, displaying the bars from 1: bars_to_display +1; then 2: bars_to_display +2, etc...

    ax.cla()
    ax2.cla()

    for i in range(step, bars_to_display + step):

        color = '#2CA453'
        if val_array[i]['open'] > val_array[i]['close']: color = '#F04730'
        ax.plot([x[i], x[i]], [val_array[i]['low'], val_array[i]['high']], color = color)
        ax.plot([x[i], x[i] - 0.1], [val_array[i]['open'], val_array[i]['open']], color = color)
        ax.plot([x[i], x[i] + 0.1], [val_array[i]['close'], val_array[i]['close']], color = color)
        ax2.bar(x[i], val_array[i]['volume'], color = 'lightgrey')

    # ticks top plot
    ax2.set_xticks(x[::3])
    # ax2.set_xticklabels(df_apple.date.dt.date[::3])
    ax.set_xticks(x, minor = True)
    # labels
    ax.set_ylabel('USD')
    ax2.set_ylabel('Volume')
    # grid
    ax.xaxis.grid(color = 'black', linestyle = 'dashed', which = 'both', alpha = 0.1)
    ax2.set_axisbelow(True)
    ax2.yaxis.grid(color = 'black', linestyle = 'dashed', which = 'both', alpha = 0.1)
    # remove spines
    ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
    ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
    # get max volume + 10%
    mx = df_apple['volume'].max()*1.1
    # define tick locations - 0 to max in 4 steps
    yticks_ax2 = np.arange(0, mx + 1, mx/4)
    # create labels for ticks. Replace 1.000.000 by 'mi'
    yticks_labels_ax2 = ['{:.2f} mi'.format(i/1000000) for i in yticks_ax2]
    ax2.yaxis.tick_right()  # Move ticks to the left side
    # plot y ticks / skip first and last values (0 and max)
    plt.yticks(yticks_ax2[1:-1], yticks_labels_ax2[1:-1])
    plt.ylim(0, mx)
    # title
    ax.set_title('Apple Stock Price\n', loc = 'left', fontsize = 20)

    ax.set_xlim(x[step] - 1, x[bars_to_display + step] + 1)
    ax2.set_xlim(x[step] - 1, x[bars_to_display + step] + 1)

    plt.draw()


plt.gcf().canvas.mpl_connect('key_press_event', on_keyboard)

on_keyboard(0)

plt.show()
```

[image]

After 20  shots:

[image]