# Interactive Stock Chart, step by step animation with a slider. Matplolib & Jupyter

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, data-visualization, finance

In this post: [Interactive Stock Chart, step by step animation with keyboard arrows, with Matplolib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68959993/interactive-stock-chart-step-by-step-animation-with-keyboard-arrows-with-matpl), I wrote a code, in which the user Zephyr brilliantly fixed, that interactively simulate a stock using keyboard arrows.
It turned out that I found a way of doing the same thing in `Jupyter`, using the module `ipywidgets`. The code works, but unfortunately the same chart is plotted twice. I have no idea why this is happening. Can someone help? I just want to show one plot (notice that the second plot does not move as I use the slider).
Here is the code:

```
%matplotlib inline
from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('all_stocks_5yr.csv')
df_apple = df[df['Name'] == 'AAPL'].copy()
df_apple['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_apple['date'])
df_apple.reset_index(inplace = True)

bars_to_display = 60
step = widgets.IntSlider(value=0, min=0, max=len(df_apple)-bars_to_display)

val_array = []
for idx, val in df_apple.iterrows():
    val_array.append(val)
    
x = np.arange(0, len(df_apple))

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize = (12, 8), gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios': [4, 1]}, sharex = True)

def f(step):
    
    ax.cla()
    ax2.cla()
    
    for i in range(step, bars_to_display + step):
        
        color = '#2CA453'
        if val_array[i]['open'] > val_array[i]['close']: color = '#F04730'
        ax.plot([x[i], x[i]], [val_array[i]['low'], val_array[i]['high']], color = color)
        ax.plot([x[i], x[i] - 0.1], [val_array[i]['open'], val_array[i]['open']], color = color)
        ax.plot([x[i], x[i] + 0.1], [val_array[i]['close'], val_array[i]['close']], color = color)
        ax2.bar(x[i], val_array[i]['volume'], color = 'lightgrey')
        
    display(fig)
    

display(step)
out = widgets.interactive_output(f, {'step': step})
display(out)
```

[image]

Comment: This doesn't address the interactive question, but you should probably be using [mplfinance](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance)

Comment: Try to replace `display(fig)` with `plt.show()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line:

```
fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize = (12, 8), gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios': [4, 1]}, sharex = True)
```

draws the first figure. Just add `plt.close()` after that.

### Complete Code

```
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import interactive, widgets
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
%matplotlib inline

df = pd.read_csv('all_stocks_5yr.csv')
df_apple = df[df['Name'] == 'AAPL'].copy()
df_apple['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df_apple['date'])
df_apple.reset_index(inplace = True)

bars_to_display = 60
step = widgets.IntSlider(value = 0, min = 0, max = len(df_apple) - bars_to_display)

val_array = []
for idx, val in df_apple.iterrows():
    val_array.append(val)

x = np.arange(0, len(df_apple))

fig, (ax, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, figsize = (12, 8), gridspec_kw = {'height_ratios': [4, 1]}, sharex = True)
plt.close()


def f(step):
    ax.cla()
    ax2.cla()

    for i in range(step, bars_to_display + step):

        color = '#2CA453'
        if val_array[i]['open'] > val_array[i]['close']: color = '#F04730'
        ax.plot([x[i], x[i]], [val_array[i]['low'], val_array[i]['high']], color = color)
        ax.plot([x[i], x[i] - 0.1], [val_array[i]['open'], val_array[i]['open']], color = color)
        ax.plot([x[i], x[i] + 0.1], [val_array[i]['close'], val_array[i]['close']], color = color)
        ax2.bar(x[i], val_array[i]['volume'], color = 'lightgrey')

    display(fig)


display(step)
out = widgets.interactive_output(f, {'step': step})
display(out)
```

[image]